# How to fire one function with different id's

Tags: javascript

I have a main PHP file that includes 8 PHP files inside. I use bootstrap class "Modal" and I use google map in each modal. So I have different IDs for showing google map, but the functionality is the same. It means, when one of each modal popup, the function will be fired and shows google map. I implement it with 8 different functions for each ID.

What I want is , is there any way to implement just by one function?

So to say more clearly, if modal popups with `id = 1`, it shows google map in `<div id="location_incident1">` and if modal popups with `id = 2`, it shows google map in `<div id="location_incident2">`, and if modal popups with `id = 3`, it shows google map in `<div id="location_incident3">` and so on.

Here is my code briefly:

```
function locationOfIncident3(current)
{
    var lat = current.coords.latitude;
    latIncident = lat;
    var lon = current.coords.longitude;
    lonIncident = lon;
    var mapOption={
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_incident3'), mapOption);

    marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        map: map3,
        draggable: true,
        title: 'Location of Incident'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'dragend', function(res){
        latIncident = res.latLng.lat();
        lonIncident = res.latLng.lng();
        getAddress3(latIncident, lonIncident);
    });
}
```

Comment: Simpy pass the id to the function as a second parameter …

Comment: any reason why `latIncident`, `map3`, ... need to be global variables as opposed to `var map3`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to preserve `map3`, `marker3`, ... variables outside of the function, you should use local variables, i.e. `var map`, `var market`, ...

The numbered string can be created dynamically using `+` concatenation operator like this:

```
function locationOfIncident(n, current) {
  ...
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_incident' + n), mapOption);
  ...
}
```

And you can refactor the calls to `locationOfIncident1`, `locationOfIncident2`, ... with a regex replace in your text editor: `locationOfIncident(\d+)\s*\(` => `locationOfIncident\($1,`